# Disadvantages of using Solver Foundation for constraint programming

Tags: constraint-programming, ms-solver-foundation

What are the disadvantages of using Microsoft Solver Foundation for CLP? Solver does have some support in the Express/Standard versions, but would imagine that one would need to buy the expensive Gurobi / Knitro add-ons to accomplish anything more than the most basic constraint programming.

Purely considering it's CLP capabilities, how does Solver compare to ECLiPSe?

Answer (score 3):

The main disadvantage is that Microsoft Solver Foundation is discontinued as a standalone product as mentioned [here](http://nathanbrixius.wordpress.com/2012/05/25/no-more-standalone-releases-of-microsoft-solver-foundation/):

> As users have pointed out, Microsoft has not been active on the Solver
>   Foundation forums since Nate left.   We have been quiet while we have
>   gone through restructuring and planning.  Some would say we have been
>   too quiet.  We know we have very loyal and enthusiastic users who want
>   to know the future of Solver Foundation.  So, here is a long overdue
>   statement about our plans for Solver Foundation.
>
> The current 3.1 release of MSF will be the last release as a
>   standalone install.  We are working hard on integrating Microsoft
>   Solver Foundation into a larger analytics framework that will help
>   users build both prescriptive and predictive analytics.  We look
>   forward to releasing this new product for your use as soon as we are
>   able to do so.  This new product will provide a migration path for
>   current Solver Foundation users and partners.
>
> We would like to continue to keep the current forum open to the
>   community to discuss MSF until the release of the new product.
>   However, Microsoft will be providing limited support of MSF in terms
>   of monitoring the forums and providing bug fixes during this
>   transition time.
>
> We have been responding to email and will continue to do so.  If you
>   have feedback on issues/bugs/improvements, we welcome your feedback
>   via msfsupport@microsoft.com.  Please check back on the forum for
>   future announcements with regards to the new analytics product.

[ECLiPSe project](http://eclipseclp.org/) on the other hand seems to be a much more established project in the area of constraint programming with substantial number of [publications](http://eclipseclp.org/reports/index.html#anclp). It is also open source, so there is no possibility for a vendor lock-in.

I'd also recommend considering:

- [“Logic” and Constraint Programming Extensions](http://ampl.com/resources/logic-and-constraint-programming-extensions/) for AMPL
- [Google CP Solver](http://code.google.com/p/or-tools/)

Answer (score 0):

Re: model sizes, For Solver Foundation Express (basic 'free' version):

- Linear or quadratic programming 50,000 non-zeros
- Mixed integer programming - 1,000 variables, 1,000 constraints, and 5,000 non-zeros
- Constraint programming - 5,000 total terms
- Non-linear programming - Unlimited

The Standard version has roughly double the capacity, and the Enterprise/Academic versions are 'unlimited' with no real restriction on core/CPU's used.

Re: advantages
A huge (IMHO) advantage of Solver Foundation is the object model approach to defining your models. Makes for easy-to-setup models programmatically in C# or to any language to which you have bindings, or you can use AMPL and MPS inputs if you want. There is a also a custom model definition language (OML) which I haven't used, but looks pretty good.

Re: disadvantage
You're tied into a proprietary setup, if that matters to you. For a GNU LP, check out [GLPK](http://www.gnu.org/software/glpk/). I've thrown some >20K contraint models at it no problems, and it has a pretty active user group.

From: [Installing Solver Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff524499%28v=vs.93%29.aspx)